# PHP display images from column value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
Table
+-----+--------+---------+
|  ID |  Name  |  Images |
+-----+--------+---------+
| 001 | John   |    5    |
| 002 | Mark   |    3    |
+-----+--------+---------+
```

i would like to display like this

```
Jon, 001-1.jpg | 001-2.jpg | 001-2.jpg | 001-3.jpg | 001-4.jpg | 001-5.jpg | 

Mark, 002-1.jpg | 002-2.jpg | 002-2.jpg | 002-3.jpg |
```

the images value on database table will be the number of images return to create images link

Comment: Seems like it would be a fairly simple php loop.  Can you give it a try?

Comment: sorry i am very new of php. thats is only a sample. actual the real database has a lot of columns and look complicated. hope anyone can help me. i know its simple but i cant do that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this though. Didn't know why you found it difficult.

```
$c = 0
while (false !== ($data = fetch_array_as_row_function()))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>", $data["name"], "</td>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $data["images"]; $i++)
        echo "<td>00", $c,"-", $i, "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Here, the function `fetch_array_as_row_function()` is something equivalent to what `mysql_fetch_array()` does.

Comment: hahaha.. thank you.. this is what i mean.. sorry.. sometimes my brain will stock ..